# Rewriting URLs to https://www

Tags: .htaccess

I've seen several topics about rewriting all URLs to https://www
But I couldn't finally set htaccess to work,
My htaccess code is the following just now :

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z]+)/rss\.xml/?$    rss.php/$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^fa/post/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?$    /post.php/$1     [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^fa/product/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?$    /product.php/$1     [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^fa/subject/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?$    /subject.php/$1      [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^fa/gallery/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?$    /gallery.php/$1      [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^fa/poll/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?$    /poll.php/$1      [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^fa/([^/]*)$    index.php/$1   [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^sitemap\.xml$    sitemap.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^posts(/?)$    posts.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^tag/([^/]*)/?$    /tag.php?value=$1     [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^cat/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?$    /tag.php?value=$2     [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://www.zanjan.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

The all URLs seems to work fine except this two :

```
zanjan.org/cat/SomeNumberHere/SomeWordHere
zanjan.org/tag/SomeWordHere
```

example 1 : http://zanjan.org/cat/2/usa

example 2 : http://zanjan.org/tag/usa

The above pages doesn't go to https://www , And with the proxy they even show me the following error(chrome):

```
zanjan.org unexpectedly closed the connection.
ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

and empty page in the FireFox..

How can I make them to work?

Comment: Move your https redirecting rule below `RewriteEngine On` line and test in a different browser.

Comment: Thank You  anubhava ! I just moved the 4 last lines to the first and it works!

Comment: Please add an answer so I can mark it as accepted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `https` redirecting rule below RewriteEngine On line and test in a different browser. In general redirect rules should be placed above all internal rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://www.zanjan.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE] 

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/rss\.xml/?$    rss.php/$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^fa/(post|product|subject|gallery|poll)/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?$ /$1.php/$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^fa/([^/]*)$ index.php/$1   [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^posts(/?)$ posts.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]*)/?$ /tag.php?value=$1     [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^cat/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?$ /tag.php?value=$2     [NC,L]
```

Also I have combined your 5 similar rewrite rules into a single rule.